# Why won't my if, else statment work in python in the while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have this code:

```
print("Christian Dooley")
print("Lab #5")
import sys

def calculation():
 counter = 0
 NumberOfElements = 1
 numbers = []
 sum = (0)
 for i in range(NumberOfElements):
     value=eval(input("Enter a new number:"))
     numbers.append(value)
 while counter <= value:
     print(counter)
     sum+=counter
     counter+=1
     if counter % 2 != 0:
         print("This number is even")
     else:
         print("This number is odd")
 print(sum)

while True:
 calculation()
 repeat = input("Do you want to 'count' another number \n Awnser yes or no: ")
 if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
      calculation()
 elif repeat == str("no") or str("No"):
      break
```

When the code runs, it should ask the user to input a number; print every number leading up to it; tell if the number is even or odd; print the sum; and finally have the user enter if he wants to repeat the process or not.

This part of the code is giving me trouble:

```
    if repeat == "Yes" or "yes":
        calculation()
    elif repeat == str("no") or str("No"):
        break
```

The if statement will keep running over and over, no matter what I enter for the repeat variable. Why does this happen?

Comment: Yep, this gets asked a lot. `repeat == "Yes" or "yes"` is _not_ the same as `repeat == "Yes" or repeat == "yes"`. The latter is what you want, because the former is always, always, always, always True :)

Comment: This one is hard to search for, to make it more fun.

Answer (score 3):

The `or` statement evaluates the first boolean, if it's False it then evaluates the second. Your second boolean statement is actually a string and strings are always True, meaning they exist. The only string that would return False is an empty string `""`.

Therefore whatever the value of the first boolean, meaning whatever the value of `repeat`, `"yes"` will always evaluate to True.

You want `if repeat == "Yes" or repeat == "yes"` or `if repeat in ['Yes', 'yes']` or better still with a set: `if repeat in {'Yes', 'yes'}`